# Find & replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xenforo

My forum has a few hundred users that have an identical expired signature from several years ago that looks like this:

```
[img]http://url.com/~expiredimage.jpg[/img]
```

The [img] tags are BBCode used to display images in the forum's script. The forum software is XenForo.

Is there a way I can mass delete all of these signatures from phpMyAdmin? If so, can you please tell me with the exact steps and query to run?

Answer (score 4):

If any occurrence of 'expiredimage.jpg' needs to be changed, you can do it directly with

```
UPDATE tablename set signature = 'new signature that you want them to have'
WHERE signature like '%expiredimage.jpg%';
```

That will change anybody with a signature that references expiredimage.jpg to the signature you specify in the query.

Comment: If I just need it deleted, is it going to be just signature and the equal sign or signature, equal sign, and empty single quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin 4.1 has a Find and replace feature, under the table Search menu.

Comment: Marc, I went into Table search for Signature, and I don't see a Find and replace there.